# react-virtualized FlexTable rowHeight based on content

Tags: react-virtualized

Is it possible to render cells in FlexTable in a way when all cell content is always visible (long texts), just like CellMeasurer for Grid but for FlexTable?

Thank You!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you give more information?

Comment: Thx for reply. Currently the height of row must be predefined, or calculated in getter function.What I wanted is something similar as CellMeasurer offers, but for FlexTable. So when in one row you have two cells and there is long text in one of the cells, all row height is extended to highest cell in a row (just like <table> behaves).

Comment: I see. That is not currently possible with FlexTable. You could do it with Grid and CellMeasurer or with Grid and a component like nkbt/react-height. FlexTable requires the row height to be calculated before a row or its columns are actually rendered.